# Navigation with parameters from custom element in Flatlist in React Native: Error: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react native and have a problem figuring out how to navigate from one class to another one with passing parameters and would appreciate your help.

All I want to do is:

1. ClassA should have a checkbox with state handling and a flatlist containing CustomButton
2. Navigate from ClassA to TargetScreen by clicking CustomButton
3. Pass parameter "element" to TargetScreen
4. Show content of parameter passed in TargetScreen

The error message I get:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
> reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html for tips about how to debug and
>    fix this problem.

ClassA:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { CustomButton} from './CustomButton.js';
import { CheckBox, SafeAreaView, FlatList} from 'react-native';

class ClassA extends React.Component {

      render() {

        const [ASelected, setA] = useState(false);

        const NavigateWithParams = () => {
            navigation = useNavigation();
            this.props.navigation.navigate('TargetScreen', { element: 'elementname' })
        }

        const renderItemCustom= ({ item }) => (
            <CustomButton onPress={() => navigateWithParams()} />
        );

       }

     return (
           <CustomConst/>
           <CheckBox value={ASelected}
             onValueChange={{setA}} />
           <SafeAreaView>
                    <FlatList
                        data={data}
                        renderItem={renderItemCustom}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.element}
                    />
           </SafeAreaView>
     );
 }

export default ClassA;
```

TargetScreen:

```
class TargetScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
       
        const { navigation } = this.props;

        return (
            
            <Text> {JSON.stringify(navigation.getParam('element'))} </Text>
        );
    }
  

}

export default TargetScreen;
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++
Update:

As of now the code looks like this:

```
class ClassA extends React.Component {
    NavigateWithParams = (element) => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('TargetScreen', { element: 'elementname' })
    }

    renderItemCustom = ({ item }) => (
        <CustomButton element={item.title} onPress={() => this.NavigateWithParams(item.element)} />
    );
    
    render() {

        return (
           
                    <SafeAreaView>
                        <FlatList
                            data={data}
                            renderItem={this.renderItemCustom}
                            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                        />
                    </SafeAreaView>

        );
    }
}

export default ClassA;
```

And I am now getting this issue:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

+++++++++++++++++++++++++
Update2

Routing:

```
   function ClassA({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <ClassAScreen/>
    );

   function Target({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <TargetScreen/>
    );
    
    //navigation stacks
    const SessionStack = createStackNavigator();
    
    function SessionStackScreen({ navigation }) {
        return (
            <SessionStack.Navigator>
                <SessionStack.Screen
                name="ClassA"
                component={ClassA}
                options={{ tabBarLabel: 'ClassA!', headerShown: false }}
                />
                <SessionStack.Screen
                name="Target"
                component={Target}
                options={{ tabBarLabel: 'works!' }}
                />
            </SessionStack.Navigator>
        )
    }
```

Logging gives me this:

```
renderItemCustom = ({ item }) => (
        <CustomButton element={item.title} onPress={() =>  console.log(this.props)} />
    );
```

[image]

+++++++++++++++++
Update:

Solution can be found here:
[Navigation with parameters from custom element in Flatlist in React Native: Empty parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67924307/navigation-with-parameters-from-custom-element-in-flatlist-in-react-native-empt/67924670#67924670)

Comment: Hooks are not allowed in class component

Comment: You are using useState in class A component

Comment: Use functional component if you wanna use hooks

Comment: thanks, could you check on my update?

Comment: Can you please console log this.props and attached screenshot??

Comment: yes, please check my latest update

Comment: Sorry, I have added the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You can’t use Hooks inside a class component

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both

**UPDATE:**

Work variant, you can try here: https://snack.expo.io/@vasylnahuliak/stackoverflow-67862370

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'first button',
    element: 'something'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'second button',
    element: 'another something'
  },
]

const HomeSceen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(route, null, 2)}</Text>
      <Button
        title="Navigate to ProfileScreen"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('ProfileScreen');
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const ProfileScreen = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  const NavigateWithParams = (element) => {
    navigation.navigate('HomeSceen', { element });
  };

  const renderItemCustom = ({ item }) => (
        <Button title={item.title} onPress={() => NavigateWithParams(item.element)} />
    );

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{JSON.stringify(route, null, 2)}</Text>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItemCustom}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
      <Button
        title="Navigate to HomeSceen"
        color="tomato"
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('HomeSceen');
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const SessionStack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <SessionStack.Navigator>
        <SessionStack.Screen name="HomeSceen" component={HomeSceen} />
        <SessionStack.Screen name="ProfileScreen" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </SessionStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: @dzitrus `ClassA` component can have `navigation` prop only if it connected in NavigationContainer. Can you show code where you inject `ClassA` component?

Comment: Just pass `ClassAScreen` into `component` prop of `SessionStack.Screen`. Don't create `ClassA` component

Comment: thanks for your response. unfortunately all i get is:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
here: this.props.navigation.navigate('TargetScreen')

Comment: also you need this steps with `TargetScreen`

Comment: same problem as in the beginning:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
in NavigateWithParams

Answer (score 0):

You cant use hooks inside a class component so remove the line which has the hook
and change like below

```
 const NavigateWithParams = element => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('TargetScreen', { element: element })
        }

        const renderItemCustom= ({ item }) => (
            <CustomButton onPress={() => this.navigateWithParams(item.element)} />
        );
```

And parameter are passed using the route prop

```
class TargetScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
       
        const { route} = this.props;

        return (
            
            <Text> {JSON.stringify(route.params.element)} </Text>
        );
    }
}
```

Also for the checkbox instead of using the useState hook, use this.state.

Comment: Thanks, that already helped me a bit, but now I am getting the following error message:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

I added this to the render(), but now I am getting the hook error again:
const navigation = useNavigation();

Not sure how to handle this, since I am not understanding the concept of hooks entirely yet

Comment: See my code, I have removed the useNavigation hook, and also use this.navigateWithParams and better move the function declarations outside render

Comment: hmm.. this is what i get:
TypeError: _this.NavigateWithParams is not a function

in this line:
<CustomButton onPress={() => this.navigateWithParams(item.element)} />

Comment: did you move the function outside render? which would remove the const part as well

Comment: if i put it within class, but before render, I am getting this:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Comment: Can you update the question with your current code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233393/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-dzitrus).

Comment: @dzitrus please show updated answer with work code example

Comment: @VasylNahuliak sorry for the late response. please check 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67924307/navigation-with-parameters-from-custom-element-in-flatlist-in-react-native-empt/67924670#67924670
I will add this to the description