# Navigation with parameters from custom element in Flatlist in React Native: Empty parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-native, parameter-passing, react-navigation

After not succeeding in solving my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67862370/navigation-with-parameters-from-custom-element-in-flatlist-in-react-native-erro), I had to create a new question with all my classes in it.

I am new to react native and have a problem figuring out how to navigate from one class to another one with passing parameters and would appreciate your help.

All I want to do is:

1. SessionCreate with flatlist containing CustomButton
2. Navigate from SessionCreate to ItemConfig by clicking CustomButton
3. Pass parameter "element" to ItemConfig
4. Show content of parameter passed in ItemConfig

With this setup an empty "element" is passed as parameter to the ItemConfigScreen (but no error occurs):

app.js:

```
//Views

function Home({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <HomeScreen />
  );
}

function Session({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <SessionScreen />
  );
}

//subviews

function SessionCreate({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <SessionCreateScreen />
  );
}


function ItemConfig({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <ItemConfigScreen />
  );
}



//navigation stacks
const SessionStack = createStackNavigator();

function SessionStackScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <SessionStack.Navigator>
      <SessionStack.Screen
        name="Session"
        component={Session}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'Session!'  }}
      />
      <SessionStack.Screen
        name="SessionCreate"
        component={SessionCreate}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'SessionCreate!' }}
      />
      <SessionStack.Screen
        name="ItemConfig"
        component={ItemConfig}
        options={{ tabBarLabel: 'ItemConfig!' }}
      />
      
    </SessionStack.Navigator>
  );
}



//Navbar Bottom
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <View style={[theme.colcontainer, { flexDirection: "column" }]} >
      
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
              let iconName;

              if (route.name === 'Home') {
                iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline';
              } else if (route.name === 'Session') {
                iconName = focused ? 'book' : 'book-outline';
              } 

              // dynamic ionicon
              return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
            },
          })}
       

        >
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Session" component={SessionStackScreen} />
          
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View >
  );
}

export default App;
```

SessionScreen.js:

```
function SessionScreen() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return (
        <View style={[theme.container, { flexDirection: "column" }]} >

                <View>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SessionCreate')}>
                        <Text >Create Session</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

        </View >
    );
}

export default SessionScreen;
```

SessionCreateScreen.js:

```
    //data
    const sessionElements = [
        {
            id: "1",
            title: "title1"
        }
    ];
    
    
    function SessionCreateScreen() {
        const navigation = useNavigation()
    
        const renderItemConfiguration = ({ item }) => (
           <CustomButton element={item.title} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ItemConfig', { element: 'item.title' })} />
 );
    
        return (
            
                <View style={{ flexDirection: "column", flex: 2}} >
                 
                    <SafeAreaView >
                        <FlatList
                            data={sessionElements}
                            renderItem={renderItemConfiguration}
                            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                        />
                    </SafeAreaView>
    
                </View >
        );
    }
    
    
    
    export default SessionCreateScreen;
```

ItemConfigScreen.js:

```
const element = "";

function ItemConfigScreen() {

    return (
        <ScrollView >
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "column", flex: 2}} >
                <Text>Configure {element} here</Text>
            </View >
        </ScrollView>
    );

}

export default ItemConfigScreen;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where's `SessionScreen` in your `navigation` tree? ... If it's not rendered as component in your app-navigation, then you won't get access to the `navigation` object

Comment: thanks for your reply. sorry, i may misunderstand, but I have the function Session(), which returns the sessionscreen. this function is called in the first component of the sessionStack. am i missing something?

Comment: it shouldnt appear in the bottom navbar, but only in the stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get parameters in ItemConfigScreen you have to use the useRoute hook from the react-navigation package.

you can read more about it here [useRoute](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-route/)

```
import {useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';
function ItemConfigScreen() {

const route = useRoute();

const element = route.params?.element;

    return (
        <ScrollView >
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "column", flex: 2}} >
                <Text>Configure {element} here</Text>
            </View >
        </ScrollView>
    );

}
```

There is also a mistake in your onPress navigation call in CustomButton, instead of 'item.title' you will have to pass `${item.title}` then only actual data will be passed. [JS Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
<CustomButton element={item.title} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ItemConfig', { element: `${item.title}` })} />
```